# symfony2 and doctrine mysql unique constraint error message

Tags: mysql, symfony, error-handling, doctrine-orm

Can you define an error message against the entity if this error occurs in symfony2?

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
```

I thought this was possible as this page seems to imply:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

So when you attempt to write to the database the error comes back just like any other constraint error?
Is the only thing to catch this error a try / catch in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `symfony-forms` to do all the basic CRUD operations in your controller that error will not happened.

When you're adding sth by an `AJAX` requests you need to check it with `try{..}catch{..}`.

Comment: CRUD operations should stop the error appearing (Crud can be made automatically by symfony2 with  
  
    php app/console generate:doctrine:crud)  
  
The link I posted in the main question should be verbatim also.